# Plank dock - hiding and showing by custom keyboard shortcut

Tags: plank

I'm looking for a toggle shortcut - hide/show Plank dock via keyboard. How can I implement this feature? To make it clear I want to Plank behaves same way as if I use a mouse cursor on it in Intelligent Hide mode.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this?

https://gfycat.com/CraftyCooperativeHarrierhawk

I implemented this just for fun. Basically it works like this:

1. Added DBus Functionality to Plank. This required to open 2 functions in HideManager.vala (hide and show) and a new Function in Interfaces.vala (i called id Show). Basically its the wrong place to add such a Functionality because it should only be used for Items on the Dock. But because its just a prototype so i added it there just for convencience. This is just a Interface for DBusManager.vala so i implemented it there for our functionality.

   ```
   [DBus (name = "net.launchpad.plank.Items")]
   interface DBusItemsIface : GLib.Object
   {
       /* omitted */

       public abstract void show() throws GLib.IOError;
   }

   class DBusItems : GLib.Object, Plank.DBusItemsIface {

       /* ommited */

       public void show()
       {
           if(controller.hide_manager.Hidden)
               controller.hide_manager.show();
           else {
               controller.hide_manager.hide();
           }
       }
   }

   public class HideManager : GLib.Object
   {
       public void hide ()
       {
           /* ommited */
       }

       public void show ()
       {
           /* ommited */
       }
   }
   ```
2. Now we can send with dbus-send a signal to activate this functionality

   ```
   dbus-send --session --type=method_call --dest=net.launchpad.plank.dock1 /net/launchpad/plank/dock1 net.launchpad.plank.Items.Show
   ```
3. Now make a script with that command and start it with a global Shortcut in Gala

**Was fun to do but i must say it isnt helpful at all. Because to be useful there should be a functionality in plank which could start applications with a shortcut (like long press Super -> Plank appears -> press 1 to start/switch to first starter)**

Comment: Yep, I agree with you.